# Is it possible to use Font Awesome icons with EvoPDF / .Net ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, font-awesome, evopdf

I use EvoPDF in Asp.Net / MVC to convert HTML into PDF.

I would like to use Font Awesome icons, but they are not displayed in the PDF result, Although Bootstrap works correctly in the same context.

The bootstrap and fontawesome files are included in the same way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/fontawesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Once rendered, the PDF shows grid layouts from bootstrap but not font awesome icons.

Comment: The font files also need to be included.

Comment: OK, I replaced the stylesheet include by the JS include and now it works.